# Click to Dial not enabled in open cti adapter

Tags: cti, opencti

I have followed the 
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Open_CTI
documentation and updated the softphone url to reflect the current org domain.

Added users to manage calls.

Now I can see call icon besides the phone field but that is in disabled mode. I am also logged in the softphone.

[image]
Does anybody faced such problem?

Call Center Configuration Screen:
[image]

Comment: which browser you are using?

Comment: I am using chrome.

Comment: Can you please share your Call Center definition pic

Comment: Actually 2 days back, I have completed this trailhead and it worked perfectly. https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/module/service_call

Comment: @SantanuBoral I have added call center definition snapshot. Please note since the definition was already present so I did not imported any call center definition file as per trailhead.

Comment: @kiranMachhewar Did you problem resolved. I have a similar issue now, I couldn't see the Click to dial option. Even I was logged into soft phone. Can you help me with this?

Comment: @MadhuSarakanam Posted answer please check.

Answer (score 1):

Solution to solve the issue is adding below script in demoCallControl page

```
<script>
enableClickToDial();
</script>
```